# How to update state from a computed property in in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to update my state data inside a computed property called `computedFirstName` but I got some problems.

I'm able to make changes to the state but it changes on every letter I typed. I don't want that I want it to change only when I click on submit button and update method is called.
Here is my code

vuex

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [vuexLocalStorage.plugin],
  state: {
    APIData: {
      userInfo: {first_name: null},
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    updateFirstName(state, newFirstName) {
      state.APIData.userInfo.first_name = newFirstName;
    },
  },
  getters: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

my component

```js
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import { getAPI } from "../../axios-base";
import VueJwtDecode from "vue-jwt-decode";
export default {
  name: "UpdateUserInfoDialog",
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["APIData"]),
    computedFirstName: {
      get() {
        return this.APIData.userInfo.first_name;
      },
      set(newFirstName) {
        this.$store.commit('updateFirstName', newFirstName);
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    update: function() {
      var user_id = VueJwtDecode.decode(this.$store.state.accessToken).user_id;
      getAPI
        .patch(
          `/rest/api/users/${user_id}/`,
          {
            first_name: this.computedFirstName,

          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$store.state.accessToken}`,
            },
          }
        )
        .then(() => {
          this.APIData.userInfo.first_name = this.computedFirstName;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**UPDATED**
I have also tried like this

```js
    computedFirstName: {
      get() {
        return this.APIData.userInfo.first_name;
      },
      set(newFirstName) {
        this.$emit("update:APIData.userInfo.first_name", newFirstName)
      },
    },
```

But with this i wont be able to make any change even on submit button

Are there anyway I can do it? Thanks!

Comment: Just store the value in data and execute a function on submit click that takes the value from data and sends it.

Comment: How can I get data from state in put it to local data()?

Comment: Attach a v-model with the name of your data prop to your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you just want a debounce when you're typing, if so install debounce package with `npm install debounce` and use something like this:

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="name" @input="saveDebounced()">
  <button @click="saveName()">Save</button>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    name: ''
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["APIData"])
  },
  mounted () {
    this.name = this.APIData.userInfo.first_name
  },
  methods: {
    saveName () {
      // update the store and call the API or call an action
      this.$store.commit('updateFirstName', newFirstName)
    },
    // you need an anonymous func here rather than an arrow
    // otherwise you have issues accessing `this`, or you can also
    // try to use this.saveName directly
    saveDebounced: debounce(function () { this.saveName() }, 500)
  }
}
</script>
```